# How can Hibernate work out whether record already exists if try and add it?

Tags: java, hibernate

I load a series of files into my application and for each file I check to see if it contains any images, if it does I then generate a checksum for the image data and check if the image is already in the database, if not I add it to the database. All database stuff is done via Hibernate.

This works fine when my code is single threaded but when it is multithreaded by call to check whether the image is in the database could return false but by the time I try to insert it it could have been added by another thread so I then have to handle the exception and make another attempt to get the image so that I can return it.

Is there anything I can do in Hibernate to help me so I don't have to do this extra coding effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checksum is the database key for the persisted image (you're not using automatically generated keys), you can use [`Session.merge()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent instance. The given instance does not become associated with the session.

See [**Modifying detached objects**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached), the [Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/) and the [Hibernate Core JavaDocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[transactions + locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html). Read the Transaction and Concurrency tutorial [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html).