# How do you manage using Hibernate in a multithreaded application when you are unsure if a record has already be created

Tags: multithreading, hibernate

How do you manage using Hibernate in a multithreaded application when you are unsure if a record has already be created.

```
Thread 1
Create Session
Do some Stuff
Create DatabaseObject
Do some more stuff
Close Session

Thread 1
Create Session
Do some Stuff
Create DatabaseObject
Do some more stuff
Commit Session
```

My problem is that Thread1 might make a number of hibernate calls, and at the same time Thread2 may well try and update/create the same object. I thought I could catch this and deal with it by catching StaleObjectException but the trouble is that the exception does not occur until I commit the transaction. This doesnt happen until the end of the method so very difficult to handle all the cases where this could occur in one place.

Alternatively I could use multiple sessions within one Thread, but the existing session is not that long running, and Im sure breaking into multiple sessions is a Hibernate anti-pattern. Or I could add some locks round code that can cause but I think I would have to break into multiple sessions again

What is the normal way of doing this ?

To give a more concrete example, Thread1 and Thread2 are both doing the same thing, processing files and amongst that adding image files .jpg, .png etc) to a database, The representation of the Image is keyed on a checksum of the data so if two files contain the same image data the image file should only be added once. Both check for the existence of an Image with matching datakey before adding to the database, but in the interim period between checking and finding no match, and then creating the image could now exist causing an exception.

Comment: For your concrete example: Use your checksum as pk and call "createOrUpdate". You would just overwrite the first entry. No exception.

Comment: You mean Hibernate saveOrUpdate(), the update() part doesnt work it only works if the Object is retrived from the database and has versioning set, otheerwise it always tries to save even if the key is the same as another record in the db.

Comment: Sorry, of course: "saveOrUpdate"

Comment: That doesnt appear to work, see @Baggio colmment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729353/why-is-hibernate-giving-constraintexception-as-if-trying-to-create-object-when-o

Comment: What about the answer you accepted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211506/how-can-hibernate-work-out-whether-record-already-exists-if-try-and-add-it?rq=1 How does the current situation differ from that one?

Comment: @xwoker heh Feb 2012 I have no recollection of that, but yes sounds like that might be the solution, thanks.